# Surface %%bash errors in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: bash, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have some Jupyter notebooks that I want to run as automated tests. I can do this from the command line by running `jupyter nbconvert --execute Test.ipynb` (is there a better way to do this?), and it will raise an Exception if any Python cell raises an Exception. I can also use the python API, which looks something like this:

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
from nbconvert.preprocessors.execute import CellExecutionError

with open(notebook_filename, 'r') as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(kernel_name='python3')
try:
    out = ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': './'}})
except CellExecutionError as e:
    raise Exception('Python notebook %s failed with error: %s' % (notebook_filename, e))
```

However, if my notebook contains a bash cell, such as...

```
%%bash 
python test.py
```

...and if the python script run in the subprocess raises an Exception, this Exception is not surfaced to the command line. To be sure, the exception is registered by the notebook and displayed, e.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception('wat') Exception: wat
```

But invoking it via the terminal or the python API produces no errors:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --execute notebooks/Test.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook notebooks/Test.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Writing 249850 bytes to notebooks/Test.html
```

How can I get Jupyter to surface these errors?

Comment: why not save the notebook as a python script and run the script? `jupyter nbconvert --to script Test.ipynb` and then `python Test.py`

Comment: @kikocorreoso That also does not raise an exception. The program prints the exception, and exits successfully.